# Confusion about Precision and Recall in Spam detection

Tags: machine-learning, classification, spam, precision-recall

I' m doing a project to detect spam accounts according to a [tutorial](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/17/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-precision-recall/). Two labels —— "Spam" and "Not spam" are used to train and test. Classification have been finished and I'm heading for evaluation.

The results are:

```
*Spam* precision: 0.962917933131
*Spam* recall: 0.6336

*Not spam* precision: 0.72697466468
*Not spam* recall: 0.9756
```

I've read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) of precision and recall, still confused and have no idea how to use it for measurement.

My purpose is to reduce the number of **Normal** accounts which is labelled as **"Spam"**. It doesn't matter that some "Spam" accounts could escape. So I want to know which result above should I focus to improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precision is the fraction of results classified as positive, which are indeed positive.

Recall is the fraction of all positive results which were detected.

> My purpose is to reduce the number of Normal accounts which is
>   labelled as "Spam".

This means you want to maximize the precision of *Spam* and recall of *Not spam*. The wiki page you link to explains all you need to know - in fact your purpose is to minimize the number of "false positives" (which is included in both of these characteristics).

Suggested keyphrase: [Confusion Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).